# Append the results of a Ruby .map into an array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby

I'm trying to build a items array. I'm looping through a CSV file and when i find matches expanding the list of items. See code below:

```
items = Array.new
csv.each_with_index do |row,i|
   items << ["a","b","c"].map {|x| row.to_s.gsub(/XXXXXXXXXX/, x.downcase)}
end
puts items.length
```

This is not returning to desired items array. Am I appended the results of map incorrectly to the array?

Comment: You don't use `i` in your example. Is it because it's just a simpler example?

Comment: Show your current result and what you would like to have as a result.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you are doing it incorrectly here:

```
items << ["a","b","c"].map
```

Items would end up as a nested array. Here's an example of what's happening here:

```
arr = []
arr << [1].map { |x| x }
arr
# => [[1]]
```

Instead, you can use `+=`.

You can also use `push` if you use the splat operator:

```
arr = []
arr.push *["a","b","c"].map { |x| x }
arr
# => ["a", "b", "c"]
```

Comment: perfect! Than you. I didn't know about the `*` what does that do exactly? I'll accept as soon as the time passes and stackoverflow lets me

Comment: it has a few uses, see [here](http://blog.honeybadger.io/ruby-splat-array-manipulation-destructuring/). In this case `push` accepts sequential arguments, so `push(:a, :b) == push(*[:a, :b]) == push(*%i{a b})`. The last one uses a shorthand to construct an array of symbols.

Comment: There's also `Array#concat`: `arr.concat %w[a b c].map { |x| x }`

Answer (score 1):

As a rule of thumb, if you're :

- initializing an empty Array
- iterating over elements, modifiying the array
- returning the Array at the end

There's a Ruby [Enumerable](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html) method to help you!

In this case, you could use [`flat_map`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-flat_map) and [`with_index`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerator.html#method-i-with_index) :

```
csv = %w(1;2;3 4;5;6 7;8;9)

items = csv.flat_map.with_index do |row,i|
   ["a","b","c"].map {|x| row.to_s.gsub(/[159]/, x.downcase)}
end

p items
#=> ["a;2;3", "b;2;3", "c;2;3", "4;a;6", "4;b;6", "4;c;6", "7;8;a", "7;8;b", "7;8;c"]
```